# Popular IDE for Struts 2

Tags: java, ide, struts2

I'm beginning to learn Struts 2, and am wondering:

Which is the most popular IDE for Struts 2?

I've looked at a few of them (netbeans, idea, eclipse) and only idea seems to treat Struts as a first class citizen. But the community version of idea doesn't have this capability.

The others have third party plugins to support it but it doesn't sound like its really 'built in'. I find this strange, given that struts is the most popular java framework.

Any hints appreciated

Comment: To be honest, i'm only guessing that struts is the most popular from my searching at indeed.com. When you say 'non standard framework' i'm not sure what you mean. So do most struts developers simply not use an IDE tailored for it?

Comment: Hang on, above i somehow replied to a comment that has since disappeared...

Comment: I moved my initial comment as answer.

Comment: By non standard, I mean not a Sun API and not a de facto standard (unlike Hibernate for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find this strange, given that Struts is the most popular Java framework.

Even if that's true, things are ephemeral in the presentation layer landscape and it might change in the future. On top of that, developing and **maintaining** IDE support for a **non standard** framework is not that light and may not be worth the effort, especially for open source initiatives. This might be an explanation.

That said, a good idea would be actually to avoid the XML configuration hell and to prefer a convention over configuration approach. The [Codebehind Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/codebehind-plugin.html) can help achieving this. Another option would be to throw Struts 2 away and to switch to the [Stripes Framework](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) >:) But this is another story.

Comment: I know, i'm sure there are nicer frameworks out there like spring mvc or stripes, but i'm learning this for the career opportunities it presents (isn't that a bit mercenary of me!). See the graph here for what i mean: http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=java+struts,+java+stripes&l=

Comment: Codebehind sounds a lot like they've been looking over the fence at Rails.

Comment: Yeah, I know this graph and Matt Raible's slides :) For your resume, Struts 2 is indeed a good choice IMO. Regarding the Codebehind plugin and the former Zero Configuration plugin, they have been heavily influenced by Stripes ideas and concepts which is actually a good thing. And maybe Stripes has itself been influence by Rails, I don't really know. But Rails doesn't have the monopole of Conventions over Configuration anyway so it doesn't really matter :)

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse with Struts 2 Plugin, this article provides details information about it [Struts-2-Eclipse-plugin](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts-2-eclipse-plugin.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

I use [IntelliJ with Struts 2 plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1698). I'm a happy user so far.

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse, but without any real plugin support.

Editing the struts xml files is a bit of a pain, but the xml valiator in Eclipse and eclipse's support for application servers and containers is pretty easy to deal with.

Comment: So is developing in struts really effective without any plugin or IDE support? In that case, what advantage does eclipse provide over, say, notepad?

Comment: Eclipse (or any other good IDE) allows you to run the server in debug mode either inside the IDE or talking to the IDE, so you can debug code with breakpoints and all that jazz.

Also, the syntax checking, validation, ant integration, maven integration, and all the OTHER plugins are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Eclipse & MyEclipse.

MyEclipse was slightly more tailored to developing STRUTS webapps because you could start a Tomcat instance within it, and edit JSPs for real time changes.  Not that you couldn't do this in Eclipse without setup.  MyEclipse also had a graphical representation of the struts-config, but it wasn't really useful for large setups.

Most of my JSPs & config files were editted in TextPad...

Comment: Similarly to the first answerer, you're saying that you simply used textpad. It sounds like most struts developers don't really use an IDE much?

Comment: @Chris: I'm not aware of an IDE for STRUTS specifically.